# Dynamic table DB design opinions

Tags: database-design, mariadb

i need some advice or opinions of "best practices" to clean up the mess i did (quick and dirty) a year ago (to show my idea) wich grew quite quick.
We have around 10 tools (growing by 5 Tools per year) in multiple remote sites wich i collect MetaData from.
We are talking about MariaDB :)
My DB currently consists of around 20 Tables with minor size and a big Table with the actual MetaData - 35 columns and around 800k Entries (around 200MiB) and is growing by 100k entries each month.

Beside that i need to restructure my DB to reduce the number of columns to around 20 i could separate the MetaData Table dynamically by Tool.

Is it a good idea to to rely on dynamic tables? (i think yes because the number of tables will still be low)
Can i get significant performance gains by that, given that i do quite some statistics updated multiple times per hour on that Data? (i think maybe, because i still need to look through that data, but dont need to filter so heavily, also when i add Datasets i do not need to check against so many rows if its separated).

Are ArchiveTables a good idea for older Datasets? TablePartitioning?

Kind regards

Johannes

Comment: Could you please update your post with your table schema and your proposed idea for changes to "*separate the MetaData Table dynamically by Tool*" so it's a little more clear what you're trying to do? If you're basically saying you want to have copies of your `MetaData` table for each `Tool`, and the columns and type of data is the same in each table, the only difference is the data is specific to that `Tool` in each table, then that's generally not a good design pattern and unnecessary for performance reasons, especially with a smaller table of only 800,000 rows.

Comment: thanks for your answer
** If you're basically saying you want to have copies of your MetaData table for each Tool, and the columns and type of data is the same in each table, the only difference is the data is specific to that Tool in each table** 
Yes, thats exactly what i thought of. So its already the answer i looked for :)

Comment: What is a "dynamic table"?  Show us the schema and point out what is "a mess".  What are the slow queries; we may be able to help speed them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like each of your Tools wants a different "view" of [the same] data.
If that's the case, then why not create a View on the MetaData table for each tool and only return the columns that the Tool requires?

```
-- Base Table 
select c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, ..., c35 
from MetaData ; 

-- Tool1 column subset
create view Tool1View as 
select c1, c2, c5 
from MetaData ; 

-- Tool2 column (and row) subset
create view Tool2View as 
select c1, c2, c3, c4 
from MetaData 
where c5 = 'T2Subset' ;
```

Comment: that sounds great, in combination with @J.D. this seams like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE` and `ALTER` should be minimized once the application is built.

Apps like WordPress are built on flexible schemas, but performance suffers.  "Entity-Attribute-Value" is the generic term for the schema they use.

`PARTITIONing` is useful only in a few cases, such as "purging old data".